# Any examples of useful Amazon Redshift SQL User Defined Functions?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, stored-functions

I'm wondering if anyone can share an example of how they have utilized a redshift user-defined function to help them optimize a query or script.

In the Redshift documentation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_CREATE_FUNCTION.html - the example is pretty basic and is probably more work to just write the function.

I feel like they could be useful when writing long scripts but I couldn't find any examples to spark inspiration!

Comment: I've seen it used to do complex extractions from a string, or to calculate values with complex formulas. A Scalar UDF only returns one value and can't access the database, so it basically converts an input value to an output value. If something more complex is required, then use a Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 1):

I can share my project, a set of AWS Lambda based user defined functions (UDF) that allow one to do direct/reverse geocoding using SQL statements, delegating this task to the newly released Amazon Location Service. Check it out on:

https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-redshift-location-user-defined-functions.

The project contain all the source code to setup the UDFs, the IAM roles, the AWS Lambdas in a CloudFormation template. You can even Launch it in your account clicking on the "Lauch Stack" button.

It's a completely functional sample, please check.